# LINQ Left Outer Join combined with Let

Tags: c#, linq

In a previous question I asked how I would get a Customers first Order, it was answered thus :

```
var minOrders = from customer in DataSet.Customers                 
let order = (from o in DataSet.Orders where o.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId
order by o.OrderTimestamp                              
select o).first()
select new {
    customer.Name,
    order.OrderAmount
});
```

This is great, but how do I include a Left Outer Join onto the above?  That is, return all Customers even if they have no orders, so something like :

```
var minOrders = from customer in DataSet.Customers LEFT OUTER JOIN
let order = (from o in DataSet.Orders where o.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId
order by o.OrderTimestamp                              
select o).first()
select new {
    customer.Name,
    order.OrderAmount
});
```

I know, in hindsight I should of asked this at the same time..

Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, using `let` to do the join like this isn't ideal in the first place. There's a `join` clause in LINQ for a reason :)

Left outer joins aren't *specifically* supported in LINQ, but you can fake them like this:

```
var minOrders = from customer in DataSet.Customers                 
                join order in DataSet.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.OrderTimestamp)
                     on customer.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
                     into customerOrders
                let order = customerOrders.FirstOrDefault()
                select new {
                    customer.Name,
                    OrderAmount = order == null ? 0m : order.OrderAmount
                };
```

Usually a left outer join uses `from foo in bar.DefaultIfEmpty` instead of `let foo = bar.FirstOrDefault()` but in this case you're only after the first match anyway, hence the different approach.

I'm pretty sure this works *logically* - whether the SQL translation will work or not is a different matter.

Comment: Null values ​​were not displayed with .DefaultIfEmpty() not show same result like using LET, this solve my problem with nested JOINs...